# I am getting a value for return instead of my database information

Tags: php

I am getting a value for return instead of getting my data from my database. The code should be good. Here is my code:

```
function getConfigurationData($configuration_value, $configuration_name_value) {
$sql = "SELECT '".$configuration_value."' FROM configuration WHERE name = '".$configuration_name_value."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row[$configuration_value];
}

<? getConfigurationData("value", "configuration_website_name"); ?>
```

What is wrong with my configuration. I seem not be returning my data and instead I get a value

Comment: Try a print_r of $row and see what you get.  You might be able to parse the result differently to get the desired result.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is wrong (quotes around field name)

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT ".$configuration_value." FROM configuration WHERE name = '".$configuration_name_value."'";
```

and a more readable way

```
$sql = "SELECT $configuration_value FROM configuration WHERE name = '$configuration_name_value'";
```